# PHP Unable to set a private variable in an extended class

Tags: php, class, extend

Trying to extend the FPDF class in PHP with the following code:

```
class Reports extends FPDF{

        var $reporttitle = 'TEST';

        function settitle($titlename){      
            $this->$reporttitle = $titlename;
        }
        function header(){
            $this->SetMargins(.5,.5);   
            $this->Image('../../resources/images/img028.png');
            $this->SetTextColor(3,62,107);
            $this->SetFont('Arial','B',14);
            $this->SetY(.7);
            $this->Cell(0,0,$this->$reporttitle,0,0,'R',false,'');
            $this->SetDrawColor(3,62,107);          
            $this->Line(.5,1.1,10,1.1);
        }
    }
```

I instantiate the class with the variable $pdf and attempt to call the method:

```
    $pdf = new Reports('L','in','Letter');  
    $pdf-> settitle('Daily General Ledger');
    $pdf->AddPage();
```

I get an internal 500 error....debugging tells me that $reporttitle is an empty property.  Can anyone provide me with some insight on how to set variable fields in an extended class?  Thanks you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use the dollar sign to prefix class properties:

```
            $this->reporttitle = $titlename;
```

PHP evaluates your `$reporttitle` first because you used the dollar sign, so you essentially were doing:

```
$this-> = $titlename;
//     ^ nothing
```

To deomonstrate, if you first delcared `$reporttitle = 'reporttitle'`, it would work.

---

Also it's worth noting that your variable is not private, it's public because you used the PHP4 `var` syntax:

```
var $reporttitle = 'TEST';
```

If you want a private variable then use the PHP5 access keyword. Remember that private variables are not accessible to derived classes so if you have a class that extends `Reports` then `reporttitle` won't be accessible.

```
private $reporttitle = 'TEST';
```

Comment: I originally had it set as private - I was fooling arounf with the code, trying to figure out the error.  I have set it back to private.  Thanks, MrCode!

Answer (score 1):

```
$this->$reporttitle = $titlename;
```

should be:

```
$this->reporttitle = $titlename;
```